# Calculate distance between li element and viewport using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, position, viewport

As shown in figure below...

Black box is the screen size, the viewport.
The red dotted box is the size of the entire page, which has been scrolled out of the viewport. The green dotted boxes are `li` elements. Now I want to calculate the distance between a specific `li` and the top edge of the viewport, represented by the red arrow.

I'm okay with a jQuery solution.

[image: screen and viewport scratch]

Comment: damn, I can only see blue dots, no green, either I am colour blind, or my monitor needs adjusting, either way, I think I fail this test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var distanceToTop = document.querySelector("#your-li").getBoundingClientRect().top
```

Comment: it's easier to use `getBoundingClientRect`

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy with jQuery too :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYrMJB)

```
$('#element').offset().top-$(window).scrollTop();
```

Best of both worlds :

```
$('#element')[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
```